# Extracting string from filenames within a file

Tags: bash

new to bash scripts and trying to `grep` for a string in a list of directories:

directory.txt contains the following

```
/apps/work/txt.out
/apps/work/Monday.txt
/apps/garbage/howdo.file
```

What I want to do is for each line in directory.txt, read the file and `grep` for a string.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: I want to see if any of the files in the directory list contain the word BLOCK

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as this:

```
search="BLOCK"

while read -r filename; do
  [ -f "$filename" ] && grep "$search" "$filename"
done < directory.txt
```

The while loop gets its input from `directory.txt`, puts each line into the variable `$filename`, checks if the file actually exists and if so executes the `grep` command on it

Comment: perfect! that is exactly what i needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
cat directory.txt | xargs grep word
```

Replace `word` with your own pattern.

Comment: That returns the full file path, as well as the string i'm after.  This in fact will suit me better!    Thanks for the help all, I'm going to play around with this now